# how to set view controller as a rootviewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift

I have two classes AppDelegate.swift and scene.swift and My first screen is login screen when I click login button then it should set my HomeVC.swift as rootViewController at the action of login button  I mentioned this code and its not giving any error not even running

```
    let sceneDelegate = SceneDelegate()
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeVC") as! HomeVC
    sceneDelegate.window?.rootViewController = vc
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Can somebody guide me how to work with new file sceneDelegate.swift?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What file is this posted code in? Never create your own instance of `SceneDelegate`. Are you supporting only iOS 13 or do you also need to support iOS 12?

Comment: Support ios 12 as well

Answer (score 0):

> when I click login button then it should set my HomeVC.swift as rootViewController

```
let vc = // ...
self.view.window?.rootViewController = vc
```